# Unable to download IPA application on device, using Enterprise Distribution Program (Ad Hoc DISTRIBUTION)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am getting this error when trying to install an app to a device. Error: Download Failed Safari cannot download this file.

My app is using a distribution certificate and mobile provisioning profile. It is uploaded to a build server where it is download on MAC machine but not in device. The server generates an application download link which I am using on my device to download the app, where I am getting the error: Download Failed Safari cannot download this file.

Comment: Do you have implemented the manifest file on the server. Is the index.html file set up? Did it work some time in the past?

Comment: i have created two file .plist and .ipa files

Comment: You would also need the .html file set up

Answer (score 0):

Try this as i believe server generates an application download link which is valid.

While creating `Ad Hoc DISTRIBUTION`, we need to provide `url link` for it, the problem while `copying` server generated url link to make url link for Ad Hoc DISTRIBUTION `white space` might be `left` in `begining`:

```
 yourServerGeneratedDownloadLink/yourApplicationName.ipa
```

**remove white space from begining**

**Second reason** may be u `forgot code sigining entity`(profile). As a result after providing code sigining entity, generate ipa again. Now create `Ad Hoc DISTRIBUTION`

**third reason** `your device` has not been `added` in `profile` which has been `used` for `generating ipa file`.